# How to extend the height of a TextField in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want to make the height of my `TextField` much bigger (it should take up almost half the screen). I am using this code:

```
 concordText = new TextField("");
 concordText.setPrefHeight(400);
 concordText.setPrefWidth(80);
```

This does increase the size of the `TextField`, but the text starts from the middle (as shown in the picture). How do I make it start from the beginning of the text?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you talking about `TextBox` or `TextField`?

Comment: @Abra - Since there's no such thing as a `TextBox` and the code shows a `TextField`, I think it's safe to assume to which they're referring :)

Comment: @Zephyr, there used to be a `TextBox`. Since the OP didn't state which JavaFX version [s]he's using, maybe it's 1.3 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a `TextField` is only meant for a single line of text, you want to use a `TextArea` instead.

In order to make the `TextArea` extend to vertically to fill its available space, wrap it in a `VBox` and set the VGrow priority accordingly:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
VBox.setVgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed.